# C array of pointer

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

For illustration,two dimensional pointer arrays in C like `int* x[][4]` can be declared ,where first index can be fixed at run time that it is dynamic then can i say that dynamic declaration of  dynamic one-dimensional array can be achieved in someway by replacing the second index to value 1 like `int*[][1]` and for two dimensional array dynamic two-dimensional array by `int*[][][1]` Does `calloc()` `malloc()` internally use them is my logic correct at all and  this  applied that is in a simplistic case of dynamic array declaration use inside a function in C language program

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: yes - "why should I make my post readable?"

Comment: *...two dimensional pointer arrays in C like `int* x[][4]` can be declared*. What C compiler and options are you using that doesn't flag this as an error (array size missing)? Or are you referring to an argument to a function?

Comment: Remember the C axiom: *Just because you can doesn't mean you should.*

Comment: @tadman Works equally well for Jurassic Park.

Comment: `int *[][1]` is still a two-dimensional array. The one-dimensional version is `int *[]`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons It would have been a really boring movie if they didn't, though! "Here we have an island with no dinosaurs. Scientists were too busy arguing about if they should, so they didn't." Roll credits.

Comment: `int *[][][1]` is illegal. Only the first dimension can be dynamic.

Comment: you mean that these declarations will generate errors/ warnings and an invalid and impossible??

Comment: and will not serve my desired usage purpose??

Comment: @tadman Mr. Smith Goes To Washington or 12 Angry Men were pretty decent movies about people arguing.

Comment: `calloc()` and `malloc()` just allocate blocks of dynamically-allocated memory of the specified size, with the blocks aligned for any object type (except for object types that specify extended alignment), so that the returned pointer can be converted to a pointer to the desired object type.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Both movies needed more T-Rex.

Comment: "you mean that these declarations will generate errors/warnings and an invalid and impossible??" Yes, only the first dimension can be left blank, and only if there is an initializer, or if the "array" is actually a parameter declaration, where it will be automatically changed into a pointer.

Comment: @stacklooker ... *you mean that these declarations will generate errors/ warnings*. You mean you didn't even apply the effort to try these out to see this for yourself? *...and will not serve my desired usage purpose??* Since we don't know what that higher purpose is, we can't answer that one. Maybe you should really state your purpose and ask how you can achieve it.

Comment: Inside a function, you can use variable expressions for the array dimensions, as long as the array does not have static storage duration. I don't know if that will serve your desired usage purpose.

Comment: so can i  have  function add that has as argument the dimensions of two multiplication compatible matrices  and inside the function perform matrix multiplaction please bother to give an example code of this example that i just mentioned or any other that you find suitable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For illustration,two dimensional pointer arrays in C like `int* x[][4]`
>   can be declared

Only in two cases:

1. when an initializer for `x` implicitly conveys the value of the first dimension,

   ```
   int* x[][4] = { {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}, {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL} };
   ```
2. as the type of a function parameter.  In that case, it is exactly equivalent to declaring the parameter to have type `int *(*)[4]`: pointer to array of four pointers to `int`.  *And that would also be the case if the first dimension were actually given.*

   ```
   void foo(int* x[][4]);
   ```

> ,where first index can be fixed at run time

In case (1) above, no, the first dimension is determined at compile time.

In case (2) above, not exactly.  It is then the declaration of a pointer to a 1D array.  Such a pointer can point to the first element of a 2D array of `int *`, and it can be indexed as if it in fact designated such a 2D array. The size of the first dimension is not *conveyed*, but if the pointer in fact points to an object then that dimension is *fixed* for the function's purposes, whether the pointed-to object is dynamically allocated or not.

> that it is
>   dynamic then can i say that dynamic declaration of dynamic
>   one-dimensional array can be achieved in someway by replacing the
>   second index to value 1 like int*[][1]

That change produces a *statically* different type (in those contexts where it is valid at all).  In case (2), but not case (1), both this type and the one we were discussing previously can point to a dynamically-allocated object, but they can also point to an automatic- or static-duration object of appropriate type.  There's nothing inherently dynamic there.

> and for two dimensional array
>   dynamic two-dimensional array by int*[][][1]

No.  Not even for the type of a function parameter.  At most the (one) leading dimension can be omitted.

> Does calloc() malloc()
>   internally use them

Not at all.  How could they?  The allocation functions do not see this datatype at all.  You tell them only how much space to allocate, either as a single composite value (`malloc`) or as an (element count, element size) pair (`calloc`).  Thus the caller needs to know how much memory is needed.  And this in any event applies only in case (2).  Case (1) inherently produces static or automatic allocation, not dynamic.

> is my logic correct at all

No.

> and this applied that
>   is in a simplistic case of dynamic array declaration use inside a
>   function in C language program

Neither as a local variable of a function (case 1) nor as a function parameter (case 2).